# Twitter API method (statuses/user_timeline) returning all user data against every tweet?

Tags: xml, api, twitter

Is it just me or is it ridiculous that when retrieving users statuses, every single tweet also contains the full information about the user? So if I want to retrieve 200 tweets from a single user, I will get the user information (name, profile colours, description, etc.) duplicated 200 times! The user information per tweet is probably 150% more data than the individual tweet data! That's a lot of wasted data to download on a mobile device!

Is there not some hidden parameter to not return user information?

Comment: @ Andrew Hare, why did you edit the question and remove the last paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's ridiculous. It's also ridiculous that they don't document what encoding they use, and that they use lossy encoding to change angle-brackets into HTML entity codes, and that their JSON is poorly formed, and goodness knows what else. It's amateur hour!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline), you can use the `trim_user` parameter to return a "trimmed" user object that contains only the user ID that is associated with the status.

An example using [twurl](http://github.com/marcel/twurl):

```
$ twurl "/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?count=200&trim_user=true"
```

That piece of information (the `user` object) is still going to be repeated many times, but it will take up a lot less space.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, it's for consistency.